# How to do something like "Class<? extends MyClass >" in C#

Tags: c#, java, reflection

I need to use reflection in C# and i know it have a `Type` object that let you work with reflection like Java's `Class` do, but i need to specify a type or subtypes like the Java code below:

```
public class Test{

    class Test2 extends Test { }        

    public static void doSomething(Class<? extends Test> myClass){
        //doSomething with class...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        doSomething(Test2.class); //ok
        doSomething(String.class); //error
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the .NET framework, Type isn't generic. There's only one type Type. You can't specific that you only want a Type that describes a type derived from a given type, at least not statically.

You can of course do

```
public class Test
{
    public void DoSomething(Type myClass)
    {
        if(!typeof(Test).IsAssignableFrom(myClass))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("myClass must refer to Test or a derived class", "myClass");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought is about generics too.. but I can't see the link with the reflection part

Comment: It's about generics AND reflection, i'll edit main post for clarify.

This way i'll need to do something like `Type type = myclass.getType()`, right?

Comment: I've updated my answer to fit your question. Sorry that I misunderstood it at first.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want constraints on type parameters?

```
public class Student<T> where T : Person
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx